# Prim's Algorithm in C++ implementation with letters

Tags: c++, graph, prims-algorithm

This is a working Prim's algorithm taking in three `int`s. My issue is that my edges are letters, and not numbers. I can't seem to debug it to make it work with `char`, instead of `int`, so I am turning to you guys. Any help would be appreciated!

```
using namespace std;
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f

// iPair ==>  Integer Pair
typedef pair<int, int> iPair;

// This class represents a directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices

    // In a weighted graph, we need to store vertex
    // and weight pair for every edge
    list< pair<int, int> > *adj;

public:
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor

    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int u, int v, int w);

    // Print MST using Prim's algorithm
    void primMST();
};

// Allocates memory for adjacency list
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<iPair> [V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int u, int v, int w)
{
    adj[u].push_back(make_pair(v, w));
    adj[v].push_back(make_pair(u, w));
}

// Prints shortest paths from src to all other vertices
void Graph::primMST()
{
    // Create a priority queue to store vertices that
// are being preinMST. This is weird syntax in C++.
// Refer below link for details of this syntax
// http://geeksquiz.com/implement-min-heap-using-stl/
priority_queue< iPair, vector <iPair> , greater<iPair> > pq;

int src = 0; // Taking vertex 0 as source

// Create a vector for keys and initialize all
// keys as infinite (INF)
vector<int> key(V, INF);

// To store parent array which in turn store MST
vector<int> parent(V, -1);

// To keep track of vertices included in MST
vector<bool> inMST(V, false);

// Insert source itself in priority queue and initialize
// its key as 0.
pq.push(make_pair(0, src));
key[src] = 0;

/* Looping till priority queue becomes empty */
while (!pq.empty())
{
    // The first vertex in pair is the minimum key
    // vertex, extract it from priority queue.
    // vertex label is stored in second of pair (it
    // has to be done this way to keep the vertices
    // sorted key (key must be first item
    // in pair)
    int u = pq.top().second;
    pq.pop();

    inMST[u] = true;  // Include vertex in MST

    // 'i' is used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
    list< pair<int, int> >::iterator i;
    for (i = adj[u].begin(); i != adj[u].end(); ++i)
    {
        // Get vertex label and weight of current adjacent
        // of u.
        int v = (*i).first;
        int weight = (*i).second;

        //  If v is not in MST and weight of (u,v) is smaller
        // than current key of v
        if (inMST[v] == false && key[v] > weight)
        {
            // Updating key of v
            key[v] = weight;
            pq.push(make_pair(key[v], v));
            parent[v] = u;
        }
    }
}

// Print edges of MST using parent array
for (int i = 1; i < V; ++i)
    printf("%d - %d\n", parent[i], i);
}
```

I tried changing the `typedef pair` to `<char, char>`, and the `*adj` to `<char, char>`. The problem arrives in the function `addEdge`, using the `list` to create my graph.

Comment: How are you expecting the prim algorithm to work when you replace the edge weights by some character?

Comment: [link] (https://gyazo.com/21fa958f76596c3fa26ccb1899729b16)

Comment: But thats only letters at the nodes, not at the edges. So your pair would need to be `pair<char, int>`. Admitted, your problem won't be solved with this, because the whole algorithm depends on numbered nodes. Do you really need to change it to char or would it possibly be enough to keep the algorithm as is and add another array where you map from node number (int) to node name (char)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be taken [from here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prims-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/).
When you run the code online there everything works fine.
You can diff your version with the theirs see what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is taken from there. The issue is being able to use this code with char, and not int.